# How to show\hide symbols according scales

Tags: arcgis-desktop, symbology, scale

How to show\hide symbols according scales,

I couldn’t figure out if there is a way to **hide symbols depending on scales** the same way we do with labels.

For example, in the screenshots below, the “community layer” is categorized according the “classification field. The labels can be turned on\off depending on scales. How the symbols can be turned on\off according scales?

[image]

[image]

Comment: After seeing the other answers, here are some additional links that show user have been struggling with this for a while. As Chris W mentioned, the simplest would be to add the layer multiple times and group them together to set a scale if necessary, or set them individually. https://geonet.esri.com/thread/22121
https://geonet.esri.com/thread/77507

Answer (score 2):

Essentially the same way the labels are. Go to the General tab instead of the Label tab of the layer properties. There you'll find the same Scale Range settings as for labels. However, unlike labels, the layer itself doesn't offer classes so you can't have one group show up at scale A and another at scale B. The way around this is to add the data as multiple layers, either with a definition query or adjusted symbology such that undesired values aren't rendered, and set each to show in its own scale range.

Comment: This seems like a good workaround to me. I was going to say that it couldn't be done directly in ArcMap based on this link but can be done programmatically.
http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/14476/changing-symbology-as-per-scale-reference-in-arcmap
Your solution would be easier to implement if it is just needed for a map or map service.

Comment: @jbchurchill I was about to say you shouldn't have removed your comment since it's highly related (and didn't show up when I searched because of the subtle differences). That particular question is about having *different* symbols at different scales, but the implementation is pretty much the same and I think it's good to have that question linked to this one. This answer basically appears there as well as part of artwork's answer.

Comment: Yes this method works but its a little bit messy, as i am publishing the mxd as a service file for a web mapping application ( Geocortex Essentials ) the site will be messy and having the same layer twice will mislead the end user, is there any other methods can be done to overcome this issue ?

Comment: @Ahmadsaleh Short of putting the valid scale range in the name of the layer, the only thing I can think to investigate further would be the ScaleDependentRenderer that Kirk mentioned in his answer at the linked question.

Comment: Thanks Chris W, but does anyone know how to start doing this job using ScaleDependentRenderer